# Eclipse RCP maven build 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.update.configurator 3.4.600.v20200422-1910' error

Tags: maven, osgi, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm trying to change from Eclipse RCP 3.7(Indigo) to 4.16(2020-06). I'm building with maven and I'm getting that error.

```
Installation failed.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
    Software being installed: CUBRID Migration 9.3.0.202401030657 (com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product 9.3.0.202401030657)
    Missing requirement: toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.update.configurator 9.3.0.202401030657 requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.update.configurator 3.4.600.v20200422-1910' but it could not be found
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: CUBRID Migration 9.3.0.202401030657 (com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product 9.3.0.202401030657)
        To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingcom.cubrid.cubridmigration.product.configuration [9.3.0.202401030657,9.3.0.202401030657]
    Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: toolingcom.cubrid.cubridmigration.product.configuration 9.3.0.202401030657
        To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.update.configurator [9.3.0.202401030657,9.3.0.202401030657]
!SESSION 2024-01-03 15:57:49.248 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_292
java.vendor=Red Hat, Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=ko_KR
Framework arguments:  -eclipse.keyring /tmp/tycho308611027236551686secure_storage
Command-line arguments:  -eclipse.keyring /tmp/tycho308611027236551686secure_storage -debug -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 10053 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE Software being installed: CUBRID Migration 9.3.0.202401030657 (com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product 9.3.0.202401030657)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE Missing requirement: toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.update.configurator 9.3.0.202401030657 requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.update.configurator 3.4.600.v20200422-1910' but it could not be found
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 1 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE Cannot satisfy dependency:
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE From: CUBRID Migration 9.3.0.202401030657 (com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product 9.3.0.202401030657)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingcom.cubrid.cubridmigration.product.configuration [9.3.0.202401030657,9.3.0.202401030657]
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 1 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE Cannot satisfy dependency:
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE From: toolingcom.cubrid.cubridmigration.product.configuration 9.3.0.202401030657
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2024-01-03 15:57:49.249
!MESSAGE To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.update.configurator [9.3.0.202401030657,9.3.0.202401030657]
There were errors. See log file: /home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/workspace/.metadata/.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] cubridmigration 1.0.0 .............................. SUCCESS [  0.047 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.common.configuration 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT ..... SUCCESS [  1.207 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.core 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT ..... SUCCESS [  1.890 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.ui 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT ....... SUCCESS [  0.974 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.command 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT .. SUCCESS [  0.252 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.common.update 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT ............ SUCCESS [  0.145 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.app 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT ...... SUCCESS [  0.238 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.plugin 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT ... SUCCESS [  0.223 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.app.feature 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.191 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.plugin.feature 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.068 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.common.update.feature 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [  0.498 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.plugin.update.site 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.064 s]
[INFO] com.cubrid.cubridmigration.app.update.site 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.063 s]
[INFO] CubridMigration Product 9.3.0-SNAPSHOT ............. FAILURE [  2.156 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.327 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-03T15:57:49+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:1.7.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) on project com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product: Installation of product com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product for environment win32/win32/x86_64 failed: Call to p2 director application failed with exit code 13. Program arguments were: [-metadataRepository, file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product/target/,file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product/target/targetPlatformRepository/, -artifactRepository, file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product/target/,file:/resolution-context-artifacts@%252Fhome%252Fcubrid%252Fmaven_update%252FCMT%252Fcom.cubrid.cubridmigration.product,file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.common.configuration/target/,file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.common.update/target/,file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.app/target/,file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.core/target/,file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.ui/target/,file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.app.feature/target/,file:/home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product/target/,file:/home/cubrid/.m2/repository/, -installIU, com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product, -destination, /home/cubrid/maven_update/CMT/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product/target/products/com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product/win32/win32/x86_64/cubridmigration, -profile, DefaultProfile, -profileProperties, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, -roaming, -p2.os, win32, -p2.ws, win32, -p2.arch, x86_64]. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:1.7.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) on project com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product: Installation of product com.cubrid.cubridmigration.product for environment win32/win32/x86_64 failed
```

I think you need 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.update.configurator 3.4.600.v20200422-1910', but I don't know how to solve the problem.
Could you please let me know if there is anything that can help me?

I added dependency to pom.xml and tried building.
But to no avail.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.update.configurator</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.600</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh... Indigo is older than a decade (2011?) ... Also the question is if JDK 1.8 which you are using is the right base for that... because JDK11 or even hight might be necessary?... And If I remember correctly the used tycho version should be aligned with the targeted update???

Comment: The work environment can only be used up to Java 8, so it cannot be raised above 11..
So I used Eclipse versions 4.16 (2020-06), tycho 1.7.0, and java 8.
Should I use a different tycho version? When I changed it to 2.0.0 and built it, it's not even building...

Comment: Adding a dependency to the pom.xml, as you have done, has no effect when using Maven Tycho (such dependencies are for plain Java applications to be resolved at compile time; this is not enough for OSGi where you can start and stop bundles/plugins at runtime). For RCP application, add the missing dependency to your target platform definition file. Make sure to read the [Plug-in Migration Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/nav/2_3). Updating to something that is already 14 releases behind is not recommended.